# Grover's algorithm and Battleship solution

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, grovers-algorithm

I have read that quantum computers are not known to be able to solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time. However, if you consider a game of Battleship with grid size $X, Y$ and represent this by a binary string $01100\cdots$ of size $X \times Y$ where the $1$s represents ship locations, wouldn't Grover's algorithm be able to solve this in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{XY})$?

Battleship is considered NP-complete. Why isn't this considered polynomial time?

Comment: Can you include the reference where you read that?

Comment: You might want to double check the difference between the *game* played between 2 people and the *decision problem* [(pdf link)](http://www.mountainvistasoft.com/docs/BattleshipsAsDecidabilityProblem.pdf)/[puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(puzzle)) - in both, you want to find all the ships but while the former involves large amounts of guesswork, the latter is a very different problem where the solution can be found without guesswork

Comment: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/The_Limits_of_Quantum_Computers.pdf

Comment: @QCQCQC How's that PDF relevant?

Comment: I was asked to provide reference to where I read that QCs are not known to be able to solve np-complete problems in polynomial time. Guess I replied to the wrong post. @Mithrandir24601 I will look into that article, thanks

Comment: @Mithrandir24610 You are of course absolutely right! I was not aware that the puzzle existed! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you've simplified the problem too much.  The way your question is framed it sounds like you expect a square-root speedup of a small problem, which doesn't seem that impressive.  In actuality there may be a Grover-style speedup not of $O(\sqrt{X Y})$ but of $O(\sqrt{2^X 2^Y})$.

Let's set up the problem, and see what is to be solved.

Let's let your opponent's battleship grid be of size $X\times Y$.  It is populated with $s\in\{0,1\}$ binary numbers, where $1$ is "ship" and $0$ is "sea".  Thus you can think of your opponent's grid as an element $S$ of $\{0,1\}^{XY}$.

The size of and placement of ships further constrains what $S$ can be; for example, there must be two consecutive $1$'s for a destroyer, four consecutive $1$'s for a battleship, etc.

Nonetheless your goal is to guess the location of all of your opponent's $1$'s with fewest number of guesses.

Thus, you are trying to determine $S\in \{0,1\}^{XY}$.  When properly framed this can be a $\mathsf{3SAT}$ instance and Grover's algorithm can get the polynomial speedup of an exponential problem.